# What is the difference between airflow trigger rule "all_done" and "all_success"?

Tags: airflow

One of the requirement in the workflow I am working on is to wait for some event to happen for given time, if it does not happen mark the task as failed still the downstream task should be executed.

I am wondering if "all_done" means all the dependency tasks are done no matter if they have succeeded or not.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#concepts-trigger-rules

all_done means all operations have finished working. Maybe they succeeded, maybe not.

all_success means all operations have finished without error

So your guess is correct

Comment: @pgoggijr yes it does, SUCCESS, FAILED, UPSTREAM_FAILED, SKIPPED all count.

Answer (score 15):

**SUMMARY**
The tasks are "all done" if the count of SUCCESS, FAILED, UPSTREAM_FAILED, SKIPPED tasks is greater than or equal to the count of all upstream tasks.

Not sure why it would be greater than? Perhaps subdags do something weird to the counts.

Tasks are "all success" if the count of upstream tasks and the count of success upstream tasks is the same.

**DETAILS**
The code for evaluating trigger rules is here https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/ti_deps/deps/trigger_rule_dep.py#L72

1. *ALL_DONE*

The following code runs the `qry` and returns the first row (the query is an aggregation that will only ever return one row anyway) into the following variables:

```
successes, skipped, failed, upstream_failed, done = qry.first()
```

the "done" column in the query corresponds to this: `func.count(TI.task_id)` in other words a count of all the tasks matching the filter.
The filter specifies that it is counting only upstream tasks, from the current dag, from the current execution date and this:

```
 TI.state.in_([
                    State.SUCCESS, State.FAILED,
                    State.UPSTREAM_FAILED, State.SKIPPED])
```

So `done` is a count of the upstream tasks with one of those 4 states.

Later there is this code

```
upstream = len(task.upstream_task_ids)
...
upstream_done = done >= upstream
```

And the actual trigger rule only fails on this

```
if not upstream_done
```

2. *ALL_SUCCESS*

The code is fairly straightforward and the concept is intuitive

```
num_failures = upstream - successes
if num_failures > 0:
... it fails
```

Answer (score 9):

Consider using [ShortCircuitOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/operators/python_operator.html#ShortCircuitOperator)  for the purpose you stated.

Answer (score 4):

All operators have a trigger_rule argument which defines the rule by which the generated task gets triggered.

I used these trigger rules in the following use cases:

**all_success**: (default) all parents have succeeded

**all_done**: all parents are done with their execution.

```
To carry out cleanups irrespective of the upstream tasks
succeeded or failed then setting this trigger_rule to ALL_DONE is always useful.
```

**one_success**: fires as soon as at least one parent succeeds, it does not wait for all parents to be done

```
To trigger external DAG after successful completion of the single upstream parent.
```

**one_failed**: fires as soon as at least one parent has failed, it does not wait for all parents to be done

```
To trigger the alerts once at least one parent fails or for any other use case.
```

[Reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#concepts-trigger-rules)

Comment: Updated link: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#concepts-trigger-rules