# How to Trigger a DAG on the success of a another DAG in Airflow using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

I have a python DAG `Parent Job` and DAG `Child Job`. The tasks in the `Child Job` should be triggered on the successful completion of the `Parent Job` tasks which are run daily. How can add external job trigger ?

**MY CODE**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
from utils import FAILURE_EMAILS

yesterday = datetime.combine(datetime.today() - timedelta(1), datetime.min.time())


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': yesterday,
    'email': FAILURE_EMAILS,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG('Child Job', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@daily')

execute_notebook = PostgresOperator(
  task_id='data_sql',
  postgres_conn_id='REDSHIFT_CONN',
  sql="SELECT * FROM athena_rs.shipments limit 5",
  dag=dag
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set dependencies between DAGs in Airflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022323/how-to-set-dependencies-between-dags-in-airflow)

Comment: @LuckyGuess The example shows one task another dag triggers another another task in another task. Here what I think what he looking, completion of one DAG completly triggering the next DAG. If you could show an example it would great.

Comment: I'd highly recommend using [`TriggerDagRunOperator`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459863/3679900) to perform **reactive triggering** rather than `ExternalTaskSensor` to perform **poll-based triggering**

Comment: @y2k-shubham, If you could write an example as the ones written below, it will be learning for others as well. I am also facing same issue.

Comment: **@pankaj** I've added an answer depicting usage of `TriggerDagRunOperator`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Answer is in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022323/how-to-set-dependencies-between-dags-in-airflow) already. Below is demo code:

Parent dag:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 4, 29),
}

dag = DAG('Parent_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@daily')

leave_work = DummyOperator(
    task_id='leave_work',
    dag=dag,
)
cook_dinner = DummyOperator(
    task_id='cook_dinner',
    dag=dag,
)

leave_work >> cook_dinner
```

Child dag:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.sensors import ExternalTaskSensor

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 4, 29),
}

dag = DAG('Child_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@daily')

# Use ExternalTaskSensor to listen to the Parent_dag and cook_dinner task
# when cook_dinner is finished, Child_dag will be triggered
wait_for_dinner = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='wait_for_dinner',
    external_dag_id='Parent_dag',
    external_task_id='cook_dinner',
    start_date=datetime(2020, 4, 29),
    execution_delta=timedelta(hours=1),
    timeout=3600,
)

have_dinner = DummyOperator(
    task_id='have_dinner',
    dag=dag,
)
play_with_food = DummyOperator(
    task_id='play_with_food',
    dag=dag,
)

wait_for_dinner >> have_dinner
wait_for_dinner >> play_with_food
```

Images:

Dags

[image: Dags]

Parent_dag

[image: Parent_dag]

Child_dag

[image: Child_dag]

Comment: I tried this I am getting an timeout error.`[MainThread] INFO airflow.task.operators - [2020-05-01 09:51:14,444] {{external_task_sensor.py:115}} Poking for RS_Input_Cleansing.events_input_sql on 2020-04-29T23:00:00+00:00 ... 
[MainThread] ERROR airflow.task - [2020-05-01 09:51:14,508] {{taskinstance.py:1088}} Snap. Time is OUT.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 955, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)`

Comment: If the `Parent Dag` is already in success status. If trigger the `Child Dag` manually will run?

Comment: You probably need to open an another question and post the full log. But to answer your question, yes, if `RS_Input_Cleansing.events_input_sql` is finished on time, child dag will run automatically

Comment: Last Task of parent dag took 2 hours to complete. Is that reason for timeout because  we have given 1 Hr for timeout

Comment: yea, increase the `timeout`. Now it's set to 3600 sec which is 1 hour.

Comment: Be aware that I also set `execution_delta` and `start_date`, you should probably remove them if you don't need them.

Comment: @LuckyGuess, Can you have look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61555430/how-to-do-store-sql-output-to-pandas-dataframe-using-airflow/61562437#61562437. I really liked your explaination style with example

Comment: This will not work if the Child Dag knows nothing about Parent Dag. A better solution would be to make it more event driven

Answer (score 12):

As [requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61514887/how-to-trigger-a-dag-on-the-success-of-a-another-dag-in-airflow-using-python?noredirect=1#comment108884062_61514887) by [**@pankaj**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8783789/pankaj), I'm hereby adding a snippet depicting **reactive-triggering** using `TriggerDagRunOperator` (as opposed to **poll-based triggering** of `ExternalTaskSensor`)

```
from typing import List

from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperator
from airflow.models.dag import DAG
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

# DAG object
my_dag: DAG = DAG(dag_id='my_dag',
                  start_date=..)
..
# a list of 'tail' tasks: tasks that have no downstream tasks
tail_tasks_of_first_dag: List[BaseOperator] = my_magic_function_that_determines_all_tail_tasks(..)
..

# our trigger task
my_trigger_task: TriggerDagRunOperator = TriggerDagRunOperator(dag=my_dag,
                                                               task_id='my_trigger_task',
                                                               trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS,
                                                               external_dag_id='id_of_dag_to_be_triggered')
# our trigger task should run when all 'tail' tasks have completed / succeeded
tail_tasks_of_first_dag >> my_trigger_task
```

*Note that snippet is for reference purpose only; it has NOT been tested*

---

Points to note / References

- [Get all Airflow Leaf Nodes/Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43529948/3679900)
- [Wiring top-level DAGs together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51325525/3679900)
- [What is the difference between airflow trigger rule “all_done” and “all_success”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41670256/3679900)

Comment: It worked . It my child ran on the success on parent . I still have a doubt.The dag of my child is `dag = DAG('Child', default_args=default_args, catchup=False, schedule_interval='@daily')` . My parent DAG is scheduled to run at 8:30 AM . The child job run after the Parent DAG finishes after 8:30 AM run and also it runs again at 12 :00 AM. I am missing something in the DAG.

Comment: **@aeapen** you might want to set `schedule_interval` of your child DAG to `None`. That ways it wouldn't ever be run automatically by Airflow; and would only be triggered upon completion of parent DAG

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for [SubDags operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/subdag_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.subdag_operator.SubDagOperator), running a Dag in a bigger dag.
Note that creating many subdags like in the example below gets messy pretty quick, so I recommend splitting each subdag in a file and importing then in a main file.

The SubDagOperator is simple to use you need to give an Id, a subdag (the child) and a dag(the parent)

```
subdag_2 = SubDagOperator(
        task_id="just_some_id", 
        subdag=child_subdag, <---- this must be a DAG
        dag=parent_dag, <----- this must be a DAG
        )
```

It will look like this:
[image: this]

From [their examples repo](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/airflow/example_dags)

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.example_dags.subdags.subdag import subdag
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.subdag_operator import SubDagOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
def subdag(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name, args):
    dag_subdag = DAG(
            dag_id='%s.%s' % (parent_dag_name, child_dag_name),
            default_args=args,
            schedule_interval="@daily",
            )

    for i in range(5):
        DummyOperator(
                task_id='%s-task-%s' % (child_dag_name, i + 1),
                default_args=args,
                dag=dag_subdag,
                )

    return dag_subdag

DAG_NAME = 'example_subdag_operator'

args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'start_date': days_ago(2),
        }

dag = DAG(
        dag_id=DAG_NAME,
        default_args=args,
        schedule_interval="@once",
        tags=['example']
        )

start = DummyOperator(
        task_id='start-of-main-job',
        dag=dag,
        )

some_other_task = DummyOperator(
        task_id='some-other-task',
        dag=dag,
        )


end = DummyOperator(
        task_id='end-of-main-job',
        dag=dag,
        )

subdag = SubDagOperator(
        task_id='run-this-dag-after-previous-steps',
        subdag=subdag(DAG_NAME, 'run-this-dag-after-previous-steps', args),
        dag=dag,
        )

start >> some_other_task >> end >> subdag
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am looking for another case. Probably I might have confused . Parent Dag is another job basically and Child Dag' is another job. I am want trigger Child' after the successful completion of the first job. If you could help me on that , it would be nice

Comment: @aeapen what do you mean by `job` is it a task, a DAG ?   This code is doing exactly what you are describing... The only thing you would do to match your case is add the Parent Dag in the end of this pipeline. I'll update the dag to demonstrate it...  But the mindset is instead of having two different DAGs independently you have nested DAGS, Parent -> Child... this makes more sense to me

Comment: the other approach would be triggering one DAG from another DAG using ExternalTaskSensor operator, which is much more confusing in my opinion

Comment: @aeapen I updated my solution, does this suits more what you want ?

Comment: I mean Job is A DAG,which contains multiple tasks.

Comment: So do I need use SubDagOperator or ExternalDagSensor for this purpose?

Comment: You can potentially do what you want with any of them, I suggest going with subdags... it's much more maintainable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212872/discussion-between-aeapen-and-bernardo-stearns-reisen).

Comment: I don't need to add `start, someother tasks and end`. You added them just for illustration right

Comment: @aeapen yes... I put them to ilustrate what the Parent DAG does before you call the Child DAG.

Comment: I M kind of confused,Can you what for loop in Dummyoperator does .

Comment: It just creates 5 operators inside of the subdag... I suggest copying and pasting this code in a dag file and check in airflow

Comment: you can click on the subdag and check the subdag tasks in the airflow ui

Comment: If the` Parent Dag' is already in success status. If trigger the 'Child Dag' manually will it run? . Here I am external sensor method

Comment: @aeapen if you add subdag inside the parentdag it will only flag the parent dag as sucess when  the subdag finishes... I think you still confused about some major concepets in airflow, if you want describe your scenario for me in the chat

Comment: @Bernardostearnsreisen, Can you have look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61555430/how-to-do-store-sql-output-to-pandas-dataframe-using-airflow/61562437#61562437. I really liked your explaination with example here