# How to do store sql output to pandas dataframe using Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I want  to store data from SQL to Pandas dataframe and do some data transformations and then load to another table suing airflow

Issue that I am facing is that connection string to tables are accessbale only through Airflow. So I need to use airflow as medium to read and write data.

How can this be done ?

**MY code**

```
Task1 = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='Task1',
    postgres_conn_id='REDSHIFT_CONN',
    sql="SELECT * FROM Western.trip limit 5 ",
    params={'limit': '50'},
    dag=dag
```

The output of task needs to be stored to dataframe (df) and after tranfromations and load back into another table.

How can this be done?

Comment: I am also looking for similar solution

Comment: Good Question, I am also facing excat same issue. Looking forward to the solution

Comment: @LuckyGuess, Any solutions from your side

Comment: @Bernardo stearns reisen, Any solutions from your side

Comment: @Bernardostearnsreisen, Can you look at this question. I really liked your explinations while answering questions with examples . I think is useful for many people

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there's an in-built operator for this. You can easily write a custom operator

- Extend `PostgresOperator` or just `BaseOperator` / any other operator of your choice. All custom code goes into the *overridden* [`execute()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/ce50538503a4e670830ff26cfa42c162049e9253/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L702) method
- Then use [`PostgresHook`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/ce50538503a4e670830ff26cfa42c162049e9253/airflow/providers/postgres/hooks/postgres.py#L29) to obtain a `Pandas` `DataFrame` by invoking [`get_pandas_df()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py#L110) function
- Perform whatever transformations you have to do in your `pandas` `df`
- Finally use [`insert_rows()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py#L264) function to insert data into table

---

**UPDATE-1**

As requested, I'm hereby adding the code for operator

```
from typing import Dict, Any, List, Tuple

from airflow.hooks.postgres_hook import PostgresHook
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
from pandas import DataFrame


class MyCustomOperator(PostgresOperator):

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, destination_table: str, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.destination_table: str = destination_table

    def execute(self, context: Dict[str, Any]):
        # create PostgresHook
        self.hook: PostgresHook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id=self.postgres_conn_id,
                                               schema=self.database)
        # read data from Postgres-SQL query into pandas DataFrame
        df: DataFrame = self.hook.get_pandas_df(sql=self.sql, parameters=self.parameters)
        # perform transformations on df here
        df['column_to_be_doubled'] = df['column_to_be_doubled'].multiply(2)
        ..
        # convert pandas DataFrame into list of tuples
        rows: List[Tuple[Any, ...]] = list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
        # insert list of tuples in destination Postgres table
        self.hook.insert_rows(table=self.destination_table, rows=rows)
```

*Note: The snippet is for reference only; it has NOT been tested*

References

- [Pandas convert DataFrame into Array of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34551914/3679900)

Further modifications / improvements

- The `destination_table` param can be read from [`Variable`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#variables)
- If the destination table doesn't necessarily reside in same `Postgres` schema, then we can take another param like `destination_postgres_conn_id` in `__init__` and use that to create a `destination_hook` on which we can invoke `insert_rows` method

Comment: ,can you demostrate with an example , it will be really helpful

Comment: @y2k-Shubam, Can you show a sample example it will really helpful

Comment: @y2k-shubham, It will be helpful you can show a sample code, I am also having a similar issue.

Comment: **@LDF_VARUM_ELLAM_SHERIAAVUM**, **@pankaj**, **@sneha nair**, **@Ria Alves** i've updated my answer to include code-snippet for reference

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very simple and basic example to read data from a database into a dataframe.

```
    # Get the hook
    mysqlserver = MySqlHook("Employees")
    # Execute the query
    df = mysqlserver.get_pandas_df(sql="select * from employees LIMIT 10")
```

Kudos to [y2k-shubham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3679900/y2k-shubham) for the get_pandas_df() tip.

I also save the dataframe to file to pass it to the next task (this is not recommended when using clusters since the next task could be executed on a different server)

This full code should work as it is.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator,
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook

dag_id = "db_test"
args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
}

base_file_path = "dags/files/"

def export_func(task_instance):
    import time

    # Get the hook
    mysqlserver = MySqlHook("Employees")
    # Execute the query
    df = mysqlserver.get_pandas_df(sql="select * from employees LIMIT 10")

    # Generate somewhat unique filename
    path = "{}{}_{}.ftr".format(base_file_path, dag_id, int(time.time()))
    # Save as a binary feather file
    df.to_feather(path)
    print("Export done")

    # Push the path to xcom
    task_instance.xcom_push(key="path", value=path)


def import_func(task_instance):
    import pandas as pd

    # Get the path from xcom
    path = task_instance.xcom_pull(key="path")
    # Read the binary file
    df = pd.read_feather(path)

    print("Import done")
    # Do what you want with the dataframe
    print(df)

with DAG(
    dag_id,
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    tags=["test"],
) as dag:

    export_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="export_df",
        python_callable=export_func,
    )

    import_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="import_df",
        python_callable=import_func,
    )

    export_task >> import_task
```