# Extract data from postgresql and insert it to Postgres in google cloud using Airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, airflow

Short: How to extract data from postgres and load to Google cloud postgres using google cloud SQL?

---

I have An airflow dag that extracts data from postgres using sqoop and stores data in AWS cloud

- is there any operator in airflow that would help to extract data from on premise datavase and load directly to postgres database on Google cloud?
- Or Can i reuse data in AWS cloud and put it directly to Google cloud database?
- Or do i need to extract CSV file form RDBMS on premise and use operators in Airflow to insert it in target table in cloud.

Comment: I suggest [postgres_to_gcs_operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/postgres_to_gcs_operator/index.html) then [CloudSqlInstanceImportOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/gcp_sql_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.gcp_sql_operator.CloudSqlInstanceImportOperator).

Comment: If you write a custom operator, you can use `PostgresHook` as told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61562437/3679900)