# How to identify airflow dependent DAGS and Tasks through airflow rest api

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver, airflow-api

i have some dependent dags (parent and child dags). How to i identify those dags are dependent ,
How to classify whether dag is dependent or not.

im using airflow version 2.4.0
How to get dependent dags details through airflow rest api.

Ref : [How to Trigger a DAG on the success of a another DAG in Airflow using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61514887/how-to-trigger-a-dag-on-the-success-of-a-another-dag-in-airflow-using-python)

Comment: by depending you mean that you call "TriggerDagRunOperator" ?

Comment: yes im using TriggerDagRunOperator .

Comment: from what i saw in the api, you can find dag that are calling other dags (without knowing the target dag_id), does it help ? i guess you are looking the info like about dag dependencies (like in the ui), but i counldn't find it in the api

Comment: yes .
also if im having target dag  id , how can i able to know dependency through rest api.

Comment: "api/v1/dags/{dag_id}/tasks" and under "tasks" you can see "operator_name": "TriggerDagRunOperator"

Comment: yeah. Suppose if im having dag details , that dag was triggered by child Dag, how can i able to know that it was triggered by child dag through rest api . Through rest api , how can able to know that particular dag was triggered by some other dag .

Comment: when you trigger the DAG using TriggerDagRunOperator you can set them both same run_id by: trigger_run_id="{{ run_id }}" , this way once you have the dag_run_id and dag candidate you can check via api/v1/dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns/{run_id}