# How to mark a dag running in Airflow as a failure through another dag?

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to create a dag that will receive the dag_id and execution_date as parameters. With this information it will mark the requested dagrun as failure.

But I'm not achieving my goal. Has anyone done something similar or can help?

My code:

```
from airflow import DAG, utils
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.utils.state import State

from airflow.models import DagRun
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__file__)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'test',
    'start_date': utils.dates.days_ago(1),
    'retries': 2,
}

 def mark_execution_as_failure(dag_id_param, execution_date_param):

     execution_param = datetime.strptime(execution_date_param, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)

     dagrun = DagRun.find(dag_id=dag_id_param, execution_date=execution_param)
     logger.info(dagrun)
     if dagrun:
         logger.info("DagRUN")
         logger.info(dagrun[0])
         dagrun[0].set_state(State.FAILED)
     else:
         logger.info(f"DAG run for dag_id {dag_id_param} and execution_date {execution_param} not found.")

with DAG(
    'mark_execution_failure',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Mark an execution as failure',
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    start_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='start')

    dag_id_param = '{{ dag_run.conf.dag_id }}'
    execution_date_param = '{{ dag_run.conf.execution_date }}'

    logger.info(dag_id_param)
    logger.info(execution_date_param)

     task_kill_dag = PythonOperator(
         task_id="kill_dag",
         python_callable=mark_execution_as_failure,
         op_args=[dag_id_param, execution_date_param],
         provide_context=True,
     )

    start_operator >> task_kill_dag
```

Comment: Please describe what you mean by *not achieving my goal*. According to the [source code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.1/_modules/airflow/models/dagrun.html#DagRun.set_state), this method does exactly what it name says, it doesn't cascade the state of DagRun's TIs. In the UI it also asks you to fail all the TIs of that DagRun. So it seem that you have to get all task instances of the DagRun and fail them individually

Comment: That's right, in this case I had to force an update directly on the TIs.


```

def mark_execution_as_failure(dag_id_param, execution_date_param):
    session = settings.Session()
    execution_param = datetime.strptime(execution_date_param, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
    query = session.query(OBJECTS[0]).filter(OBJECTST[1] == dag_id_param, OBJECTS[2] == execution_param).update({OBJECTS[3]: State.FAILED}, synchronize_session=False)
    logger.info(query)

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, in this case I had to force an update directly on the TIs.

```
def mark_execution_as_failure(dag_id_param, execution_date_param): 
session = settings.Session() 
execution_param = datetime.strptime(execution_date_param, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) 
query = session.query(OBJECTS[0]).filter(OBJECTST[1] == dag_id_param, OBJECTS[2] == execution_param).update({OBJECTS[3]: State.FAILED}, synchronize_session=False) 
logger.info(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways, in the legacy versions you had SubDAGs which are no longer recommend, you try to use

1. TaskGroup
2. Cross-DAG dependencies

Now considering what you are implementing in this code is the only way who want to approach this problem

I would recommend follow this thread -> [How to Trigger a DAG on the success of a another DAG in Airflow using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61514887/how-to-trigger-a-dag-on-the-success-of-a-another-dag-in-airflow-using-python)